# Twitter Bootstrap Grail plugin is not working

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am new in Grails. I start learning Grails before 3 days. I want to use twitter bootstrap in my sample Grail application. I am following this [tutorial](http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap)

I added `runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2'` in my grails-app/conf/BuildConfig file.

Here is my list.gsp file where I want to use bootstrap.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Posts</title>
    <r:require modules="bootstrap"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <g:link controller="post" action="edit">
        Create a new post
  </g:link>
  <div class="well"> 
  <h1>My Posts</h1>

  <g:each in="${posts}" var="post">
    <div>
      <h2>${post.title}</h2>
      <p>${post.teaser}</p>
      <p>Last Updated: ${post.lastUpdated}</p>
      <g:link controller="post" action="edit" id="${post.id}">
            Edit this post
      </g:link>
      <g:link controller="post" action="view" id="${post.id}">
         View this post
      </g:link>
  </div>
  </g:each>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my plugin list

```
plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"
    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:2.3.2'

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'
}
```

Its not working. I am completely new in Grails. I don't know why it is not working. please help..

Comment: Could you show list of installed plugins, output of console?

Comment: @baxxabit I updated my question. Please check. Its not showing any error. Plugin installed successfully but my gsp page is not showing any bootstrap feature

Comment: Are you edit your main layout?

https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin#edit-your-sitemesh-layout

Comment: I make list.gsp as a root by changing my UrlMapping.groovy file `"/"(view:"/post/list")`

Comment: Try to change main.gsp in layouts folder and restart app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32927/discussion-between-shreshtt-bhatt-and-baxxabit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to list.gsp

```
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
```

and change main.gsp in layout folder like in [this example](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin#edit-your-sitemesh-layout)